# Accessing Data in Httphandler sent using post request

Tags: asp.net, jquery, httphandler, ihttphandler

I have created a httphandler. Everything is working fine If you take the request type GET. But I really don't want GET request due to security reasons.

I am making a POST request using Jquery using following code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "SaveAccounts",
        data: { a: "Sent Data" },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function OnSuccess(a) {
            alert(a);
        },
        error: function OnError(request, status, error) {
            alert('Error: ' + request + ' ' + status + ' ' + error);
        },
        complete: function () {

        }
    });
```

And the code for processing request is:

```
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    Dim s As String = context.Request.Params("a")
    context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s))
```

This code is returning 'null' in javascript alert in client side.

Please note every thing is working fine when request type is changed to GET in $.ajax() function.

I have also tried to access posted data using context.Request.Form("a") and context.request.SserverVariables("a")

context.request.Params is a combined collection of 'Form', 'ServerVariables', 'Cookies' etc.

Please tell me where I am going wrong...??

Thanks for looking....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working by just removing contentType and dataType specification from the request.
Anything other than this will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data: { "a=Sent Data" },
```

e.g. from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Also the HttpHandlers don't like JSON data so get rid of the contentType and the dataType.

Escaping it - a more complete example

```
var dataString = "{ 'first' : '" + escape($('#fname').val()) +
    "', 'mail' : '" + escape($('#tbMail1').val()) +
    "', 'mailinglist' : '" + $("input[name='ml']:checked").val() +
    "' }";
    /*alert(dataString.replace('\',','\',\n'));*/ // just for debugging ;)

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myAjaxHandler.asmx/ProcessSampleForm",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        $(".loadingimg").fadeOut();
        window.location.replace(msg.d);
    },
    error:function(xhr,err){
        $(".loadingimg").fadeOut();
        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Taken from http://www.jphellemons.nl/post/JQuery-with-webform-input-validation-ajax-posting-json-to-aspnet-C.aspx

Comment: May be it works, but this is very unreliable. Suppose I am sending the value from textbox's text, then what if a user inclued "&" or "=" sign in input value..??

Comment: Well I checked your solution. This is also returning null value from server. Note it is still working if the request type is GET.

Comment: You need to sanitize user input always. Use escape it is a JavaScript function that allows transmission over most networks.

Comment: any way... your solution is not working.. please give me another trick to do so..

Comment: try context.Request["a"] see if that helps

Comment: Alternatively - add a page (page.aspx) and post to that - see if you can pull the variable out? If not then you have another issue going on here.

Comment: Ok I finally got a chance to check this out in VStudio and it worked fine for me. One point is that you can't use JSON to post to an HttpHandler - you need to use the more traditional name=John format as I described at the start of hte answer. Also *make sure* to drop the contentType=json, and datatype=json bits

Comment: Oh thanks @rangitatanz ..
It is working, if I remove contentType and datatype specification from request. But there was no need to use tradition query string format like var1=val1&var2=val2. This is really not fair and much unreliable if the inputs are directly from textboxes and '&', "=" or double quotes can be a valid input.
Thank god, data: {a: "val1", b: "val2"} can work..

Comment: And what if it has " or : in your textbox input as well? You have the same issue. Best practise is to escape the data *always*.

Comment: No issue if u have " or : or even any sign in your input value.
This all will be included in the user input text. I have checked it.